# PHP: unexpected 'echo' при использовании тернарного оператора в шаблоне WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, тернарный-оператор

Вывожу изображение страницы в качестве фона для блока. Поскольку не у всех страниц есть изображения, то пишу проверку: если есть thumbnail, ставить его, если нет - картинку-заглушку. В таком виде всё работает:

```
<div class="thumbnail-block" style="background-image: url(
    <?php
        if (has_post_thumbnail()) { 
            the_post_thumbnail_url(); 
        } else {
            echo get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/single-fon.jpg';
        }
    ?>
)">
```

Захотел упростить эту конструкцию и сделать проверку через тернаторный оператор:

```
<div class="thumbnail-block" style="background-image: url(<?php (has_post_thumbnail()) ? the_post_thumbnail_url() : echo get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/single-fon.jpg'; ?>)">
```

Но при такой записи получаю ошибку: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)`

Вопрос: почему при записи `if else` нет проблем с `echo`, а при использовании тернарного оператора она появляется? И как её исправить?

Comment: заменить echo на print. но правильно было бы `<?= has_post_thumbnail() ? the_post_thumbnail_url() : get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/single-fon.jpg'; ?>` если бы только вордпресс не был таким говнокодом

Comment: @Danila там чуть выше есть абзац **"No Shorthand PHP Tags"** с требованием не использовать короткий вариант записи. Но вы можете решение, приведённое выше, просто переписать в виде `<?php echo has_post_thumbnail() ? the_post_thumbnail_url() : get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/single-fon.jpg'; ?>`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129713/discussion-on-question-by-danila-php-unexpected-echo---).

Comment: @Qwertiy, первый комментарий был по сути ответом - правильным и полезным. Его не стоило переносить. А остальные можно было просто удалить.

Comment: @Danila, вернул.